# Does SonarQube specifically apply rules when analysing JSX files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube

I used SonarQube to scan all the JSX files by adding this line in `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx
```

My question is, does SonarQube apply specific rules when analysing JSX files, or does it treat JSX files the same as JS files and use the same rules?

For example, can SonarQube tell passing an empty dependency at the end of this `useEffect` might be a bad practice?

```
useEffect(() => {
   someFunction(param1, param2);
}, []);
```

By the look of the report I have, it cannot, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note you don't have to be using JSX to use hooks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does that mean using hooks in normal JS files?

Comment: Yes; JSX is commonly used but isn't a requirement for writing React generally or function-based components specifically. Also it's fairly common to use JSX syntax in files with the `.js` extension.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh yes yes, all my JSX files end in .js extension.